# PropTyped prop is of type unknow

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to achieve custom type custom for the object property. But somehow it doesn't connect and I would appreciate a lot if you could suggest why :-)

```
import {
    defineComponent,
    PropType
} from 'vue'

interface IconType {
    class: string
    file: string
}

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        icon: {
            icon: Object as PropType<IconType>,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup (props) {
        // TS2571: Object (props.icon) is of type 'unknown'.
        const iconPath = `map.svg#${props.icon.file}`

        return {
            iconPath
        }
    }
})
```

TypeChecker suggests that icon is of type `any`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the type for the `props` parameter. E.g.:

```
interface Props {
  icon: {
    icon: PropType<IconType>;
    required: boolean;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in the setup code:

```
setup (props: Props) {
```

Further explanation: The props object that you have written directly below `export default defineComponent({` is used by Vue to define valid input properties for the component, however you need the above for TypeScript to infer their types.